# Connect multiple redux sub-states to a React component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my react-redux-typescript app, I have multiple sub-states that form the application state. Application state is as follows.

```
interface AppState {
    dialogs: DialogState,
    messages: MessageState,
    notifications: NotificationsState,
    errors: ErrorState
    loading: LoadingState,
    status: StatusState;
}
```

I use `connect` method for getting one of the sub-states available in a React component as *`props`*. But now I have a case where I need two sub-states properties available in a component as its *`props`*.
Specifically these parts:

```
interface LoadingState {
    size: number
    available: boolean
}

interface StatusState {
    name: string
}
```

Usually, I use the connect method in component Loading as follows:

```
export default connect(
(state: AppState) => state.loading, actionCreators)(Loading);
```

The header of the Loading component is:

```
type LoadingProps = LoadingState & typeof actionCreators;
class Loading extends React.Component<LoadingProps, {}>
```

If I do that I have properties of the `LoadingState` interface available as props. But what should I do if I want also properties from the `StatusState` available as props in the same component?

Comment: You might be looking for something like this https://github.com/reactjs/reselect

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First your props need to also expect StatusState

`type LoadingProps = LoadingState & StatusState & typeof actionCreators`

Then your mapStateToProps function would just need to return an object containing all those properties mapped, easiest way is to use a spread (...) from the state values

```
export default connect(
  (state: AppState) => ({...state.loading, ...state.status }),
  actionCreators
)(Loading)
```